# VirtualBox add existing installation

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualbox

I have Ubuntu installed alongside windows 7. 
Is it possible somehow to add the existing Ubuntu installation as a virtual machine in windows 7?

Comment: I don't have the expertise to post an answer with all the steps, but this is possible. All of the research I've done on this kind of thing suggests you'll need to look at using the VMWare Converter app to create a VMDK file. You'll then need to convert the VMDK file to VDI format. You'll want to have a pretty big external drive to put that initial VMDK file in, as the initial process will force you to image both the Linux and Ubuntu partitions. There may be another method I haven't found while researching.